# ExtJS: Show/hide control on checkbox selectionchange

Tags: checkbox, listener, hide, show, extjs5

I have an ExtJS check-tree [ExtJS Check Tree](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#check-tree) that I am trying to add some control to based on items checked/unchecked. It doesn't seem to fire correctly though.

Here is a [Fiddle Example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1h8n)

When checkbox 'A' is selected, I want to hide the textfield, `'testValue'`, which works, but then if I unselect checkbox 'A', I want to show the textfield, `'testValue'`, which does not work.

For this test I am merely looking to see if the `selections.selected.length === 0`. However, when I unselect any of the checkboxes, the listener does not seem to be firing, since the alert message is not getting triggered - plus, if I then try to reselect the check box again it still does not fire.

I would use a selection Model (as outlined below) to achieve this (since I know it works), but then this places checkboxes on all my tree items when I just want to have the leaf nodes with checkboxes.

```
selModel: {
        type: 'checkboxmodel',
        listeners: {
            selectionchange: 'onCheckedNodesChange'
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

**EDIT**
Adding `allowDeselect: true` and a listener for `select` and `deselect` sort of worked (I updated the Fiddle to exhibit the behavior):

```
 selModel: {  
                allowDeselect: true,
                listeners: {
                    deselect: function(model, record, index) {
                        text = record.get('text');
                        alert(text);
                    },
                    select: function(model, record, index) {
                        text = record.get('text');
                        alert(text);
                    }
                }

            },
```

I want to make sure that when 'A' is selected, the textfield remains hidden, but if you select another item in the list and then deselect it, the textfield returns.

I am trying to use the getChecked() method alone with when selectionchange event occurs. However, this only seems to return data when I do a submit (for example, on the `Get checked nodes` control). Any suggestions would be most welcome. This should not be so difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tree panel we have checkchange event it is similar to the selectionchange event.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-event-checkchange

checkchange( node, checked, eOpts )
Fires when a node with a checkbox's checked property changes

Parameters
node : Ext.data.TreeModel
The node who's checked property was changed.

checked : Boolean
The node's new checked state

eOpts : Object
The options object passed to Ext.util.Observable.addListener.

```
var fields = [
            {
                name: 'column'
            },
            {
                name: 'leaf',
                type: 'boolean'
            },
            {
                name: 'checked',
                type: 'boolean'
            },
            {
                name: 'cls',
                type: 'string',
                defaultValue: 'x-tree-noicon'
            },
        ];

        this.dataModel = Ext.define('Filter-' + this.getId(), {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: fields,
        });


     columns: [
                 {
                            xtype: 'treecolumn',
                            width: 200,
                            itemId: "filter",
                            dataIndex: 'column' ,
                            renderer: function (val, metaData, r) {

                            },
                            scope: this,
                        },
                    ],
                    listeners: {
                        'checkchange': Ext.bind(function (node, checked,eOpts)         { 
                        },
                        scope: this
```

Comment: I tried this, and it does not seem to fire on `checkchange.` Please see Fiddle referenced above.

Comment: In the code the A,B,C doesnt have the childnodes right that's why the test is not alerted otherwise it will work

Comment: alert outside the if it will work I already implemented some feature using check change event its working

Comment: Yeah its not working but instead of selModel we can add a checked in the model of tree then we will get the checkboxes for all the nodes and then add listeners to items it is working

Comment: Yep, removing the `selModel` does the trick. Much appreciated, since I've been fighting with this.

Answer (score 1):

The checkboxes you are seeing are not part of the selection behaviour. Instead, they come from the [`checked` configuration](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.NodeInterface.html#cfg-checked) on the NodeInterface class.

Your tree panel is using the [default `selModel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tree.Panel.html#cfg-selModel), which is row-based selection, with no deselect option. If you want the in-tree checks to control the selection, you'll need to configure that manually, probably by listening to change events from the store.

OTH, if all you care about is finding out which items are checked or not, you can use [the `getChecked()` method on the TreePanel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tree.Panel.html#method-getChecked)